# If I schedule a cron job to run at midnight, will it run at the start or end of the day?

Tags: cron, crontab

If I schedule a cron job to run at midnight on a specific day, will the job run at the beginning of the day, or at the end of the day? For example:

```
# Runs at midnight on 20th February:
0 0 20 2 *
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is: **at the beginning of the day**, as 0:00 is the first minute of the day and 23:59 is the last.